# Unable to create EventHub Authorization Rule in Azure using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

While trying to create EventHub Authorization Rule, getting the below error message. Not able to really get through this.

**TF Code:**

```
resource "azurerm_eventhub_authorization_rule" "jdBulkMessenger" {
  name                = "jd-bulk-messenger"
  namespace_name      = azurerm_eventhub_namespace.eventhub_ns.name
  eventhub_name       = azurerm_eventhub.eventhub.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  listen              = true
  send                = false
  manage              = false
}
```

**Tried with Different Provider Version but the same issue persists:**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      version = "~> 2.29.0"
    }
  }
}
```

**Error:**

```
Error: Error making Read request on Azure EventHub Authorization Rule : eventhub.EventHubsClient#GetAuthorizationRule: Invalid input: autorest/validation: validation failed: parameter=authorizationRuleName constraint=MinLength value="" details: value length must be greater than or equal to 1
```

Comment: If your  terraform cli version is 0.12.19 , you can try  provider version like  2.56.0

Comment: Had the issue been resolved?

Comment: Yes with the new provider version, I am able to create the authorization rule successfully. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same :***

Even I had similar error `Error: Error making Read request on Azure EventHub Authorization Rule: parameter=authorizationRuleName constraint=MinLength value="" details: value length must be greater than or equal to 1` when I had ***`older arurerm provider version  2.15.0`***

**Providers.tf**

```
azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "2.15.0"
    }
```

---

### [image]

***Then I changed the azurerm provider version to 3.0.2 and it worked .***

---

[image]

---

- Check if both  **`AzureRM Provider`** and **`Terraform Core versions`** are old
  and `upgrade` to the latest versions as it may be fixed in latest
  versions.
- Also check if that azurerm provider version is compatible with terraform core/ cli version such that it supports azurerm provider version in order to create
  authorization rules smoothly.